# JPQL: Update if not exists

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sql-update, jpql

I'm trying to achieve something like this in may JPA/Hibernate/MySQL application:

```
UPDATE UserRating ur SET ur.item = :newItem WHERE ur.item = :oldItem AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ur2 FROM UserRating ur2 WHERE ur.user = ur2.user AND ur2.item = :newItem)
```

So, I want to update some rows only if they will be unique (user/item combination must be unique).

I'm getting

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'user_rating' for update in FROM clause
```

with the current JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to turn in it into `JOIN`

```
UPDATE UserRating r JOIN
(  
  SELECT user, item 
    FROM UserRating ur
   WHERE item = :oldItem 
     AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT * 
     FROM UserRating 
    WHERE user = ur.user 
      AND item = :newItem
  )
) q ON r.user = q.user 
   AND r.item = q.item
   SET r.item = :newItem
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f246d/1)** demo